# how to retrieve firebase data only if that node exists

Tags: reactjs, firebase

Firebase structure

[image]

**BACKGROUND:**

I am trying to retrieve  data and plot charts using 
https://react-google-charts.com/

**PROBLEM:**

[ERROR SCREENSHOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JpUGB.png)

[image]

If the node 'Nutrition' in firebase doesn't exist the graph doesn't work.

**CODE:**

https://codesandbox.io/s/z2l23rxzll?fontsize=14

Any suggestions, hint would be helpful, thanks in advance.

Comment: please add your code to fetch data from firestore so we get an idea.

Comment: i have pasted codesandbox link above.